# sql alchemy set foreign key field to None after commit

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

everyone. I found realy strange behaviour of SQL alchemy. When I'm trying to insert new instance of Device, after commit sql alchemy set type field to None. Here is my models:

```
class BaseTable(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True,
                   index=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.date_created = dt.datetime.utcnow()


class Device(BaseTable):
    __tablename__ = "device"

    node_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('node.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), index=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(255), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Unicode, nullable=True)
    type = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('device_type.id', ondelete='SET NULL'), index=True, nullable=True)
    type_description = db.relationship("DeviceType", lazy='joined')


class DeviceType(BaseTable):
    __tablename__ = "device_type"

    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(255), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    code = db.Column(db.Unicode(255), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
```

In device_type table there is 6 entries with id form 1 to 6.
I do simple post request for creating new device instance. Here is code of controller:

```
@accepts(schema=post_schema, api=api)
@responds(schema=main_schema, api=api)
def post(self):

    strer = ''
    result = None

    payload = api.payload

    try:
        entity = post_schema().load(payload)
        result = crud_service.post(entity, log, db_session.session)
    except Exception as ex:
        strer += str(ex)

    if result is None:
        return response500(log, strer)
    else:
        return result
```

In crud_service.post I have:

```
session.add(entity)
session.commit()
return entity
```

So, when I make post request in payload I get type of device = 5 (for example). I'm sure that I have this ID in my device_type table. But after sql alchemy do `session.commit()` type of device is None. After it, if I make put request and rewrite type with

```
ent = session.query(model)\
      .filter(model.id == dict_entity['id'])\
      .update(ent_dict)
session.commit()
```

I got type in my DB as I expected.
So, it seems that sql alchemy by doing session.add() set type field of my device to None,
but session.update() not.
Can enyone explain this behaviour? May be any trouble in my models?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I've found problem.
I delete type_description = db.relationship("DeviceType", lazy='joined') and now it works fine. I will see another way for make relationship field